# Running devenv against a .vdproj at the command line doesn't produce an MSI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-3.0, vdproj

I want to generate MSI files from a `.vdproj` file using the `devenv` command in  a command prompt. This command is running well but no MSI file is generated. What is wrong?

What should I set in environment variables, or is there any other way to generate an MSI from a `.vdproj` file?

Answer (score 5):

This is usually (in my experience!) caused by not targeting the correct build configuration. Within Visual Studio, at the solution level you can go to the `Build` menu and choose `Configuration Manager`. Ensure that for all applicable configurations (chosen via the `Active Solution Configuration` drop-down) the installer project has a tick in the `Build` column.

Now you need to ensure that when invoking devenv you're passing the appropriate build configuration (i.e. one that has `Build` ticked for the setup project) as follows:

```
C:\PathToVisualStudio\devenv.exe /Rebuild Release C:\PathToProject\ProjectName.sln" /Out "PathToProject\vs_errors.txt"
```

*(In this example, `Release` is the build configuration I'm targeting)*

This command also logs the output of Visual Studio to a text file called `vs_errors.txt` in the same folder as your solution so you can review this to determine if there are any other reasons why the setup project failed to build.

Answer (score 3):

Above script worked for me, try it and let me know if it works for you. You can pretty much have any configuration. I have used `Release|x86`. Just replace that line with your configuration and it should work. Make sure that whatever configuration you use exists in `.sln` file or `.csproj` file, otherwise you may get some error about invalid configuration. Hope this helps.

```
<target name="BuildMsi">
    <echo message="Creating installables (.msi) for MyTestApplication, please wait..."/>    
    <exec program="c:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe">
        <arg value="c:\My app\My_Test_solution.sln"/>
        <arg value="/build"/>
        <arg value="Release|x86" />
        <arg value="/project"/>
        <arg value="c:\My app\setup\My_Test_solution.vdproj"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

My case was the same, and giving the project name with /project helped with .msi file generation,

```
devenv /build Release /project SDK-Deployment SDK-Deployment.vdproj
```

Comment: Should the end of that read `/project SDK-Deployment\SDK-Deployment.vdproj`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that msi will be genereated from devenv.com , you may choose wix with nant to create installer.

Nant has a task, msi task but it requires micrsoft cabinet sdk, which is not available for download.

read this for more details [Build merge module without Devenv from .vdproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538068/build-merge-module-without-devenv-from-vdproj)

p.s. If you find another way to build the installer , please share.