# Recovering from error HRESULT = '8000000A' in CC.Net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net

I'm seeing "[An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '8000000A'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648428/an-error-occurred-while-validating-hresult-8000000a)" a lot when building with VS2010 using CC.Net.  I've installed the hotfix described therein but am still seeing the error.

The error can almost always be resolved by forcing another build manually. That's a real pain; naturally I'd like to automate it. :^)  But I'm having trouble figuring out part of the process. I know I'll need to use a conditional task block. The pseudocode for what I want to do looks like:

```
if statusCondition == Failure
  if failure is caused by HRESULT = '8000000A'    <-- this is the part I can't figure out
    Use devenv to rebuild vdproj file
  endif
endif
```

How can I use CC.Net to determine that the cause of the failure really is 8000000A? I'm not seeing anything in CC.Net's Integration Properties or Task Condition Blocks that looks like what I need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, using CruiseControl.NET's API I was finally able to solve this problem.  Woot!

First I created a C# console application to get the list of failed projects.  The log file for each failed project is inspected, and if the project failed due to error 8000000A, a build is forced on that project.

```
//Due to a race condition in Visual Studio 2010, CCNet builds often fail with error 8000000A.
//See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648428/an-error-occurred-while-validating-hresult-8000000a
//
//The build failure can almost always be fixed by manually forcing another build on the failed project.
//
//This program, along with a companion CCNet project, will automate the process of forcing the builds on the failed projects.
//  1. For each CCNet project whose IntegrationStatus == Failure
//  2. Search the most recent log file for the string "8000000A"
//  3. If string found in log file, force a build on the project

using System;
using ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote;

namespace ForceBuildForError8000000A
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CruiseServerRemotingClient ccnetClient = new CruiseServerRemotingClient("tcp://localhost:21234/CruiseManager.rem");
            ProjectStatus[] prjStatusList = ccnetClient.GetProjectStatus();
            foreach (ProjectStatus prjStatus in prjStatusList)
            {
                if (prjStatus.BuildStatus == IntegrationStatus.Failure)
                {
                    string latestBuildName = ccnetClient.GetLatestBuildName(prjStatus.Name);
                    string log = ccnetClient.GetLog(prjStatus.Name, latestBuildName);
                    if (log.Contains("ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Forcing build for " + prjStatus.Name);
                        ccnetClient.ForceBuild(prjStatus.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next I created another project in my ccnet.config file. This project uses a Multi-trigger to monitor all the other projects that can fail with the 8000000A error. When any of the trigger projects has a failure, the C# program is run to force a build on any projects that failed due to 8000000A.

```
<cb:scope ProjectName="$(ForceBuildForError8000000A.Run_ProjectName)">
    <project name="$(ProjectName)" >
        <cb:ProjectHeaderMacro projectName="$(ProjectName)" />
        <cb:AssemblyVersionLabellerMacro Major="1" Minor="0" Build="0" />
        <triggers>
            <multiTrigger>
                <triggers>
                    <projectTrigger project="$(ProjectName1)" triggerStatus="Failure" />
                    <projectTrigger project="$(ProjectName2)" triggerStatus="Failure" />
                    <projectTrigger project="$(ProjectName3)" triggerStatus="Failure" />
                    <projectTrigger project="$(ProjectName4)" triggerStatus="Failure" />
                    <projectTrigger project="$(ProjectName5)" triggerStatus="Failure" />
                    <projectTrigger project="$(ProjectName6)" triggerStatus="Failure" />
                </triggers>
            </multiTrigger>
        </triggers>
        <tasks>
            <exec>
                <executable>$(ForceBuildForError8000000A.exe)</executable>
                <baseDirectory>$(MyWorkingTrunk)</baseDirectory>
                <buildTimeoutSeconds>120</buildTimeoutSeconds>          
            </exec>
        </tasks>
    </project>
</cb:scope>
```

Note I didn't end up using a conditional task block as I originally thought would be needed, but rather a conditional trigger.

There's probably a way to do this using NANT instead of C# but I could never figure out how.