# An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '8000000A' (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 Building the Setup Project from command line.

The build from Visual Studio GUI works for debug and release.
But with command line only the source will be compiled and the installer Exit with this error message.

**ERROR: An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '8000000A'**

Any idea what can i do?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010022/an-error-occurred-while-validating-hresult-8000000a-need-a-solution-that-w

Comment: Try the solutions from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8648428/324260).

Comment: I've had this problem before and a restart of my computer solved this error for me :)

Comment: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\MSBuild]
"EnableOutOfProcBuild"=dword:00000000

And a restart of the computer solved the problem! THX