# Setup Project is missing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, setup-project, setup-deployment

Under "Visual Studio installed templates" ,Setup project is missing in Visual Studio 2012-Ultimate. How to solve this issue? Kindly clarify.

Note: I also tried re-installing the visual studio

Comment: The feature was removed, too many bugs and no Microsoft programmer left that knows it well enough to do something about it.  It is not quite gone, by popular demand you can still retrieve it [from the Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).  Not for VS2012 however afaik.

Comment: My answer here might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845705/how-to-create-a-msi-file-for-a-visual-studio-2010-solution-w-o-visual-studio-201