# VSTS build is not generating .msi file using .vdproj

Tags: azure-devops, windows-installer, azure-pipelines

I have VSTS Build which will generate the `.msi` file using `.vdproj` but I am not getting the `.msi` file out of the build.

I am getting the `Warning MSB4078: The project file "abcdSetup\abcdSetup.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built`.

I am using Visual studio build task and MS build task to generate the `.msi`.

I have tried some ways and I installed third part task called create `.msi` file from VS installer Project.

I have attached the Snapshot of all the tasks using to generate this `.msi`file.

Please have a look and help me on this and also do let us know is there any task available in VSTS to create `.msi` file.

[image]

Comment: Is this thread helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570869/vsts-online-building-setup-projects

Comment: @ yan, Thanks for your response. In the thread they are saying that Private agent has to setup. Is there any way that we can generate .msi without setting up the Private agent in VSTS ? Please let me know is there any task available.

Comment: I am working on it and let you know once I am done.Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting the Warning MSB4078: The project file "abcdSetup\abcdSetup.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built

That because MSBuild/Visual Studio does not have support for setup projects. To integrate with Azure DevOps, you will have to use devenv.

Note: starting VS 2013, .vdproj support is provided by an add-in.

That the reason why you got the error `Warning MSB4078: The project file "abcdSetup\abcdSetup.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built`

> Is there any way that we can generate .msi without setting up the
>   Private agent in VSTS ? Please let me know is there any task available.

I am afraid there is no such way you can generate `.msi` without setting up the Private agent in Azure DevOps, otherwise, we will always get the error:

```
Some errors occurred during migration. For more information, see the migration report: C:\VSTS-vs2017-agent\_work\9\s\Setup1\UpgradeLog.htm
```

I test it on the Private agent and local PC without installing the Visual Studio Installer Projects extension and got the same result. Then I installed that extension on the local PC and it works fine. So, we have to install the Visual Studio Installer Projects extension, if we want to build the setup projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo, I have setup private agent and connected with Azure DevOps I have installed visual studio installer projects extension in the local machine from this link (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) but I am not sure how to run devenv command and where exactly I can run this to create the .msi file.Please help me.

Comment: Could any one please help me on this issue?

Comment: @PDBR, If possible, please check https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1236961/How-to-create-msi-and-setup-exe-file-from-the-comm  and https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/building-vs-2015-setup-projects-in-team-build

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't possible until agent image `Windows2019` was published. The new image is  equipped with an extension for `vdproj` that is called `Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects`.

Steps:

1. Add a `Command line` task
2. Add there following line: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" MyProjectDir\MySolution.sln /Rebuild Release`

Remark: please note to use `devenv.com` (not `devenv.exe`). The "com" version outputs build log and errors to the console (standard output).

Answer (score 2):

In 2022 today, looks like the Azure DevOps includes the [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects) extension.

I was able to get a build using below pipeline configuration:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  BuildConfiguration: 'Release'
  BuildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  InstallerProject: 'YourInstallerProject/YourInstallerProject.vdproj'
  Solution: 'YourSolution.sln'
  VisualStudioPath: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install Nuget CLI'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore packages'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Solution)'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Prepare for MSI build'
  inputs:
    script: 'DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe'
    workingDirectory: '$(VisualStudioPath)\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build primary project'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Solution)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Build installer project'
  inputs:
    script: '"$(VisualStudioPath)\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "$(Solution)" /Project "$(InstallerProject)" /Build "$(BuildConfiguration)|$(BuildPlatform)"'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy MSI files'
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    contents: '**/$(BuildConfiguration)/**/?(*.msi)'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: drop
```

Make sure to update the values of `Solution` and `InstallerProject` variables. If you would like to build with a Visual Studio version other than 2022, you must also edit `VisualStudioPath` variable.

Comment: 'Restore packages' fails with this exception:
"The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid."
Seen that error before?
(variables are adjusted)

Comment: This is the best answer for VS 2022.  One note - I only could get this working once I removed  "$(Solution)" from the Build installater project cmd task script block.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @thomasmartinsen - my nuget restore task only contains the displayName, and not the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a build including a `.vdproj` MSI installer going with a modification of [VPZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405355/8491301).  Building just the installer project with the devenv command line was not working for me.  Therefore, I built the whole solution containing the installer project with the devenv command line.  I used `DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe` first.

Here are the relevant portions of the pipeline YAML configuration.

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: 'Code\IntelligentContentFramework.sln'
  visualStudioPath: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: 'x86'

steps:
# ... nuget restoration steps omitted ...

# Enable vdproj installer build from devenv command line.
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Prepare for MSI installer build'
  inputs:
    script: 'DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe'
    workingDirectory: '$(visualStudioPath)\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild'

# Build using command line that seems to work to build installer as well.
# Note: /Build would probably be equivalent to /Rebuild on fresh build VMs.
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "Command Line Build"
  inputs:
    script: '"$(visualStudioPath)\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "$(solution)" /Rebuild "$(buildConfiguration)|$(buildPlatform)"'
```