# ".vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built in Azure CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, vdproj

I've a windows service setup project (.vdproj) in the solution and it's being ignored by MS build during build pipeline.
How can I force the MS build to compile it to MSI?

Comment: Please check this answer for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646694/257470

Answer (score 1):

This question maybe a duplicate. Try to use solutions from here [VSTS build is not generating .msi file using .vdproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630699/vsts-build-is-not-generating-msi-file-using-vdproj) and here [VSTS Online Building Setup Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570869/vsts-online-building-setup-projects)

1. Use your own build agent.
2. Install Visual Studio Installer Projects extension into your build agent.
3. Use a custom step to build your project: [How to create .msi and setup.exe file from the command line using devenv.exe](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1236961/How-to-create-msi-and-setup-exe-file-from-the-comm), [Building VS 2015 Setup Projects in Team Build](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/building-vs-2015-setup-projects-in-team-build)