# Azure Devops Pipeline - Use Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, windows-installer

I'm using Azure devops with the VM = vmImage: 'windows-2019' and I would like to know how to generate an MSI file from my vdproj.

In my local visual studio I have the extension "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" installed and it works fine. But in the VS2019 of the hosted agent from Azure pipeline I dont have, and I can't generate the msi as an artifact.

I've tried to run by devenv.exe cmd but as I dont have the extension it didnt work.

Is there any way to generate msi files from azure pipeline? I've tried different ways, some custom tasks but it didnt work.

Or can I change my setups to another type of project that the MsBuild reconigze?

My error:

```
The project file "xxx.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component.VSInstallerProjects v: 0.9.9 is now installed on the Microsoft-hosted agent 2019.

Answer (score 1):

> The project file "xxx.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot
>   be built.

For this issue ,that because Visual Studio Installer Projects extension is not installed on the Hosted agent. You can view this [link](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) for a list of software installed on Microsoft-hosted agent2019.

As a work around , you have to configure your [own build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows) to run the build.

Make sure the VS Installer Projects extension is installed on your own build agent and then you can build the setup project either use command line task with "devenv" or use the "Build VS Installer" task.

To Build `.msi` file by VS installer project, you can use [Build VS Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.BuildInstaller) task in marketplace.

You can specify to build .sln or .vdproj to generate .msi file(s) in Task-mode option.

[image]

Here are the similar cases:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570869/vsts-online-building-setup-projects),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630699/vsts-build-is-not-generating-msi-file-using-vdproj) , you can refer to .

Comment: Sadly Build VS Installer doesn't work with VS 2019 yet..