# HRESULT '8000000A' in Visual Studio 2017 for WPF Project

Tags: wpf

I have created setup project for WPF application and need to setup automatic build.  So I am trying to build application from command prompt. I could not able to build setup project using following command.

`"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv" D:\Projects\Pos.sln /rebuild "Release|Any CPU"`.

```
   ` ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Pos.Setup' ------ 
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'Pos.Setup' completed ------
11>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Pos.Setup, Configuration: Release ------
========== Rebuild All: 10 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`
```

I have gone through the every website I could not able to find the answer for Visual Studio 2017.

Any help?

Comment: Why aren't you using msbuild?

Comment: msbuild will not support setup project (The project file "Pos.Setup.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built). Am using visual studio installer -> Setup Project

Comment: It seems the problem could be no installer project vsix installed on your build machine. This error and a work round is covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570869/vsts-online-building-setup-projects

Comment: I found the reason behind this error is "the new IDEs do not support build outside the own process".

https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/07/visual-studio-error-code-8000000A.html.

But I did not found MSBuild path for VS2017 to add the register key.
@Andy
I am using GIT and I need to configure JENKINS automated build.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the tool that adds the registry hack automatically, it's now part of the installation. I had the same problem today and I was able to fix it with this.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild\DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe

(change 2019 for 2017 for VS2017).

Found it on [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/715579/vs2019-building-vdproj-fails-prebuild-validation-w.html)