# Error: An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '80070057'

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, runtime-error

I'm having this error message when I try to make an `.exe` file with "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects".

I read all the post on this error, but nothing helped. Starting with Install/reinstall and finish with trying to find a file with Temporary ASP.Net files (could not find them till end).

Also, I tried it with a basic "Hello world" project on 2 PCs and one notebook. But I got the same error. The project is written in C# and XAML.

How to fix this error?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want us to do a search for you? We have no idea what you did and how you did your project. The only thing in this case what we can do is to search and post a bunch of links to same problem solutions...and this is not how the SO works.

Comment: Anyway have you checked this duplicated question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648428/an-error-occurred-while-validating-hresult-8000000a

Comment: If your project is indeed a UWP app (as the tag indicates) then you can't use the Installer Project for this app. UWP projects already have their installer built in (appx packages), so no need to build a separate installer.

Comment: I know about (appx PACKAGES). But I need for my installer a simple setup.exe Not a lot of files. And to Reniuz, I search all day for the solution that's why I'm writing here for help.  And I'm not pro but in the link above is another error.

Comment: @Reniuz it's not a duplicate - completely different error code, and at least for me that solution didn't work in any case

Comment: @OdedBenDov might be, but as I wrote in first comment - we have no idea what OP does. Simple example and explanation how it was made, what environment OP has would be a good starter.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects are not applicable to UWP applications. They are intended to be used with regular (classic) desktop applications (like WPF, Winforms, MFC, etc.). You can't build a traditional installer for a UWP app.

If you are building a UWP you should be using APPX packages as your installer technology.

If you need a traditional .msi/setup.exe then you will need to switch to developing a regular desktop app, like WPF.

Comment: So how I could use this APPX files to install my application, without any validation or smth like this, just double click and done? My application won't be published on the store.

Comment: Yes, once you have created the .appx file and signed it with a trusted certificate you can just double-click it to install. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#sideload-your-app-package