# How to build Visual studio Setup project using command-line?

Tags: c#, command-line, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, command-prompt

I have a sample WPF project and I created a Setup project to it. Now I want to build the project and Setup project through the command line.

I tried with this

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

C:\Users\nandh\source\repos\CommendApp\CommendApp\CommendApp.csproj
```

command for build the project file it is successfully worked.
[image]

Then use with

```
devenv /build Debug 

"C:\Users\nandh\source\repos\CommendApp\CommendApp.sln" /project

"C:\Users\nandh\source\repos\CommendApp\App\App.vdproj" /projectconfig
Debug
```

for build the setup project it shows error.

> ```
> ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'App' ------
> ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'
> ------ Pre-build validation for project 'App' completed ------
> ```

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Please let me know if it solves your issue. And if you have any discovery or solution you can share it as an answer :)

Comment: Yeah Sure friend.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT  The below first answer is working for the issue, and my problem was solved with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have reproduced same issue in my machine. And resolve it by workaround from [it3xl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41788791/10910450).

1. Create a Text Document file in desktop and copy the content from this [xx.bat file](https://github.com/it3xl/MSBuild-DevEnv-Build-Server-Workarounds/blob/master/workaround/DevEnv-Vdproj-VS2017_Professional-HRESULT-8000000A-EnableOutOfProcBuild.bat) into it. (for professional editon)
2. Save and rename the text document from xx.txt to `Test.bat`
3. Double click the `Test.bat` file, then this issue goes away when i rebuild them by `devenv` command.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah! it's working fine .msi file was generated successfully, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my **build.bat** script using Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension in Visual Studio 2022. Hope it helps someone.

```
@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "{{=setlocal enableDelayedExpansion&for %%a in (" & set "}}="::end::" ) do if "%%~a" neq "::end::" (set command=!command! %%a) else (call !command! & endlocal)"
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

del build.log

%{{%
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
    XXXX.sln
    /out build.log
    /build Release  
    /project XXX.Setup\XXX.Setup.vdproj
    /projectconfig Release
%}}%
```