# Creating a build for Visual Studio Deployment Project via command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, deployment-project

I am having issues with trying to create a Visual Studio **Deployment** Project via command prompt.

I have a visual studio 2015 installer I am trying to create, I am running the following command:

```
devenv.exe <SolutionName>.sln /Build "Release|Any CPU" /Project "<InstallerProjectName>.vbproj" /ProjectConfig "Release|Any CPU"
```

I also read that maybe the dependent projects need to be built as well, so I have also tried that as follows:

```
devenv.exe <SolutionName>.sln /Build "Release|Any CPU" /Project "<ProjectName>.vbproj" /ProjectConfig "Release|Any CPU" /Project "<InstallerProjectName>.vbproj" /ProjectConfig "Release|Any CPU"
```

No matter what I have tried the installer project does not build and it gives an error (pop's up the Microsoft visual studio helper window)

If I run the code without the installer such as the follow that project will be built just fine.

```
devenv.exe <SolutionName>.sln /Build "Release|Any CPU" /Project "<ProjectName>.vbproj" /ProjectConfig "Release|Any CPU"
```

What I am missing to get the installer project to build?

clarity:
- for devenv.exe I am pointing straight to the devenv.exe for VS 2015, I do have multiple versions of VS installed
- I am using "" around the locations paths to deal with the spaces in the names
- language is VB.Net

Comment: Hi friend, I'm a bit confused about whether this issue occurs only on tfsbuild or local build. Does it work well without any issue when you run the command locally?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing.
What I talk about here is all locally. Ultimately I want this to be a script on TFSBuild. This is because from what I have read MSBuild does not build Deployment projects, and i was getting errors says that MSBuild does not recognize the project.
So, what I read is that you want to create a script on the build machine to force it to then build this deployment project. And this is what I am testing here, just the script locally to just force MSBuild to build the project via cmd / script.
I may end up going a different route as this one is not working out so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions that help to locate the cause of issue and then resolve it.

1.Try using `devenv.com` instead of `devenv.exe`, so that you can quickly get output info.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019#devenv-switch-syntax): *Using devenv.exe directly prevents output from appearing on the console.*

2.For installer project, it doesn't have platform like `Any Cpu`. See this:

[image]

For `Release|Any Cpu` solution configuration, the installer project(Setup1) doesn't have `Any CPU` project platform by default. Which mean your `/ProjectConfig "Release|Any CPU"` is not valid. I think it can build if you changes it to be `/ProjectConfig Release`

3.And make sure your path is all right. For me, I opened `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015` and then navigate to solution folder by `cd C:/solutionPath`. Then i use command like this to build the installer project:

[image]

Normally the project file is in `SolutionPath/ProjectName(one folder)/projectName.vdproj`, so I use `InstallerProjectName\InstallerProjectName.vdproj` instead of `InstallerProjectName.vdproj`. (You may need to correct the InstallerProjectName.vbproj to InstallerProjectName.vdproj in your question...)

And now the devenv command will actually try to build the installer project. And if you meet `HRESULT='8000000A'`, it's known issue about installer project. Check my [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57070069/how-to-build-visual-studio-setup-project-using-command-line/57093415#57093415) for more details to resolve that. (For VS2015, you should use [corresponding way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41788791/10910450) of VS2015)

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Changing to Release worked. I tried devenv.com, but I think this takes the latest version of VS installed? I was getting errors on the projects because they are compiled for 2015 and the latest version I have is 2019. However, with pointing directly to the devenv.exe 2015 version and changing the release type to just release, worked. Thanks.