# ERROR: An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '8000000A' when building using devenv and jenkins visual studio 2019

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2019, devenv, vdproj

When building an install package (vdproj file) that contains some windows services and other c# and vb.net dll, we get the following error.  This is using vs2019 Enterprise

ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'

This is when built using Jenkins,  we have logged in as the user that runs jenkins and run the registry fixes to this to no effect.

I have also included the batch file from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41788791/2429707)

None of this works.  This is preventing our CI from working and is causing us delays.  If you logon as the user and build in visual studio it works fine and if you build on a development machine the same thing happens.

Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the tool that adds the registry hack automatically, it's now part of the installation. I had the same problem today building from TFS and I was able to fix it with this.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild\DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe